# My localizations are not taken into account

Tags: xcode, localization, xcode5

I'm trying to localize an existing application. Here is a simple thing that I can't make work:

- I have added the needed languages into localizations from the project info tab
- Activated the l10n for one of my storyboards
- Adapted the strings into the newly created `.strings` files
- Cleaned the app
- Removed the app from the simulator
- Relaunched the app in the simulator
- Changed the language in the simulator

No effect...

I am used to i18n in other languages & frameworks and I have to say I never saw it as complicated & unintuitive as in Xcode.

Could someone help me with that ? Am I forgetting something here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I fixed it:

- Disable localizations for each resource
- Make sure to have `Use Base internationalization` checked from the project's Info tab
- Move all resources that needed localizations somewhere specific (From Finder)
- Reattach the references from Xcode (with the right Utilities panel *location folder* button)
- Activate localizations for each resource selecting `Base` as base

The last step moves each file into `Base.lproj` and creates a `strings` files into each selected `{lang}.lproj`.

For future files to localize, don't put them into `Base.lproj` yourself, otherwise Xcode will create another `Base.lproj` subfolder to move the file into.

I think that Xcode organizing files into his own "groups" (almost) totally disconnected from the real folder hierarchy is the thing that constantly confuses me (not even talking about git). I don't really understand the advantage of having this detached hierarchy.